# Issue running Non-SXA site on an SXA installed Sitecore instance

Tags: sxa

We are trying to pretty much lift and shift an old on prem Sitecore 7.2 site to Sitecore 9.3 in Azure. The environment is provided to us by a different team. When they installed the 9.3 instance, they added SXA. Old site is non SXA and we lifted and shifted to a local environment where the SXA is not installed. And it works. But when we go to Azure we have issue with components data source is not honored. For Example, we have a component named navigation, and it has a placeholder name associated with it and it's datasource. When this component on a page, a non-SXA Sitecore works and brings data but if it is on the SXA enabled sitecore instance, it doesn't work. If I go to the page and goto PLD and select the component and define placeholder and datasource there, it will work. Also if I take out the SXA and JSS SXA folders from app_config/module folders, it works and the datasource in the component level is honored.
My question is> how can I have the component datasource be honored.
Also, asking for a non-sxa installation takes over 4 weeks, a time that doesn't "Disco" with us :slightly_smiling_face: (edited)

Comment: Components for SXA require a specific structure. You would need to adapt your existing components to work. Open up the views folder and inspect a component like Plain HTML to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of my team, I found a workaround. Here is the solution we found

http://mohammadhoque.com/?p=450

There are probably way to improve this, but this got us moving again.